# Manage Access Control on Swift UI Elements

Tags: unit-testing, swift, ios, uikit

I have following ViewController class with a tableView.

```
final class ListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: UserCell.reuseIdentifier)
        return tableView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
  
    }
}
```

Here I have declared the tableView instance as a public variable. Otherwise I won't be able to access it from my unit tests.

Is this way safe? Do we have any access control related problems here?

Or else I can declare my tableView as follows.

```
 private(set) var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: UserCell.reuseIdentifier)
        return tableView
    }()
```

In this case, I can access my tableView property from unit test class. Also we can't change it from outside classes.

But the problem is, I have declared it as a mutable property. Is it adhere to best practices?

Since we aren't going to change this tableView inside our class is it a must to declare it as an immutable property?

Which way is better? Or any other ways to doing that?

Comment: potential [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56058681/1575353) as well as [related answer about the same concept but the question is about c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1093481/1575353)

Comment: The `tableView` instance is **internal**, not public. There are [a few ways](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/testing-private-methods-variables/) to expose your class to tests.